# Extending integrable almost-complex structure

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $(X,I)$ is an almost-complex real analytic manifold where $I$ is a real-analytic almost complex structure.  Suppose there exists an $I$-almost complex submanifold $M\subset X$ where this means that $M$ is a real analytic submanifold such that given a tangent vector $v$ to $M,$ then $I(v)$ is also tangent to $M.$  Suppose that the restriction of $I$ to $M$ is integrable.  The question is: are there conditions under which this implies that $I$ is integrable on all of $X?$  I would be supremely surprised if the condition was empty, namely that this always implied that $I$ was integrable, although I wouldn't look a gift horse in the mouth.  Nevertheless, a condition such as the restriction of $I$ to $M$ being Stein, or something of such a global nature, doesn't sound quite so ridiculous.

I should add that in the exact situation I'm considering, $X$ is non-compact (it's topologically a ball) and $M$ is non-compact (also topologically a ball) and the restriction of $I$ to $M$ is Stein, and lots of other nice things you might dream it to be as a complex manifold.

**Edit**:  I've just realized that I need to add that $M$ is *not* of complex dimension one, otherwise the integrability of $I$ restricted to $M$ is a trivial consequence of there being no $(2,0)$-forms on $M.$

Thanks for any comments or ideas you might have.

Comment: I think it would be messy to write down an example, but my intuition says that there should be lots of examples. Since a ball is Stein, we just take the usual complex structure on the ball $\mathbb{B}^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^3$, and perturb it as an almost complex structure away from a complex linear subspace $\mathbb{C}^2$. I think we will get no other complex surfaces in the resulting  $X$ other than $M=\mathbb{B}^2 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Also if you start with $M\subset X$ of complex dimension $1$, then $M\times\mathbb{C}\subset X\times\mathbb{C}$ will be of complex dimension $2$ and it will be Stein if $M$ is.  You still won't be able to 'extend' integrability in such a case.  Starting with $X$ having complex dimension $2$, you can see that you can have $M\times\mathbb{C}^k\subset X\times\mathbb{C}^k$ for any $k$, so even codimension $1$ won't help you without some further hypotheses.

Comment: For better or worse, I think these comments close the question.  I'm not sure how to proceed, but thanks.